# Is it right to use std::condition_variable::wait inside a while loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, condition-variable

I am currently working on the std::condition_variable. Is it right to use std::condition_variable::wait() inside the while loop and not to rely on the std::condition_variable::notify() at all?

> Should each std::condition_variable::wait() mandatorily have std::condition_variable::notify() ?

Comment: Unless you `notify` the condition variable, waiters will wait forever.

Comment: I'm uncertain what you are asking.  Can a function call wait and not notify?  Sure.  Can a program work if it only contains wait and never a notify?  Well, once any wait is called, the thread will never advance, so what do you mean by work?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont actually thread may advance due to spurious wakeup, but I doubt anybody should rely on that behavior.

Comment: Ah yes, the good old "program works, but only spuriously"

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes this was what I am interested in. Spurious wake up.  But the question is if this way of coding is right and reliable.

Comment: @Boanerges No, spurious wake ups are not reliable.  Relying on them happening or not happening is not the right way to code with condition variables.  Your question remains vague enough that I strongly suspect that the answer may be misleading you.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont NO! I am not misled. I wanted to know this because I was dealing with an existing code written like this. So I wanted to know there was a specific reason to write it this way. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use it in a loop, and you rely on `notify()`.

The problem is that a condition variable is allowed to wake up "spuriously", that is, without being signaled. That makes it easier to implement, but it requires you to check that you're really where you think you are. So you write a loop:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(some_mutex);
while (condition_not_satisfied())
    cond_var.wait(lk);
```

Where `some_mutex` provides a critical area for the variable(s) used in the condition.

Or, as Slava points out, you can use the predicate version:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(some_mutex);
cond_var.wait(lk, some_callable_object_that_checks_the_predicate);
```

(I've never liked that form, so I tend to forget about it)

Comment: "so you write a loop" or you use a predicate version

Comment: There's another, better reason for the loop: In a multi-consumer application, one thread may wake up because of a notify_all, and discover that some _other_ thread already has handled the event. In that case, you usually want the first thread to go back and await the next event.  Even if spurious wakeup was not a thing, it still would be good practice to always loop, just so that some other programmer reading your code would not have to spend time trying to figure out why it was OK in your particular application to _not_ write it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow -- good point. I **knew** there had to be a good reason for not liking the predicate form. <g>

Comment: Uh Oh. I think I answered the wrong question then, because the "predictate" form is required to be equivalent to the loop. That is to say, the predicate may be tested more than one time before the `wait(...)` returns. My experience is mostly Java, and in Java there _is_ no predicate form. I am used to explaining to Java noobs why it is seldom appropriate to call `wait()` just one time without looping.

Comment: @SolomonSlow -- my view is that making the loop explicit makes the code clearer. Given that bias, that's what I read into your comment.

Comment: The predicate version has sane, simple state before, in the predicate, and after.  The loop version is "do X then Y then Z or you are screwed" style programming to a greater degree.  And yes, they are equivalent, except structurally: the structure of the loop one is more complex.  The predicate version really shines in `wait_for`.

Comment: I suggest you to give a look at Item 39 of Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers. In practice, you can use either a condition variable or a promise/future. If you use a condition variable the detecting function use a locked bool (not atomic) and `cv.notify_one()`, while the reacting function use a locked `cv.wait(lk, [] {return flag; });` to avoid spurious wake-ups.

Comment: @severalpeople, Yes. In most programming languages or standard libraries, `wait()` and `notify()` or the equivalent are the most primitive way in which one thread can wait for another. Ideally, you want to hide wait() and notify() inside the implementation of higher level constructs--blocking queues, futures, barriers, mailboxes,...--that express what the thread is waiting for in a more natural, more application-specific way.